# IWebBrowser2 - IOleInPlaceFrame : how to find which proxy is used

Tags: c++, c, winapi, proxy

In my C++ application, I created a IWebBrowser to embed IE web browser. I'm a beginner and I don't know how can I get the current proxy used for my integrated web browser. Is it in the IWebBrowser2 or IOleInPlaceFrame object ? Do you have any example of code to get current proxy used ?

Please help me

Thank you in advance